# create a button in android not changes when scrolling / static

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

i'm new in android.
i have looking for how to make a button create new message like in bbm/whatsapp, i have set the layout.

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_req_out_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgNewReq"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ico_circle_additem" />
    </ScrollView>
```

and i want when scroll up and down, the position not changed.

Please help, thanks

Comment: position not change of what button ? the view which you don't want to scroll put that out of scrollview

Answer (score 1):

put the button outside scrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_req_out_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNewReq"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_circle_additem" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```